# Combine two facet_wrap extensions (facet_rep_wrap and facet_wrap_paginate)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I have found 2 useful `ggplot2` extensions:

- `lemon::facet_rep_wrap()` repeats axis lines and labels across all facet panels
- `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate()` splits facet panels over multiple plots

Now, I would like to apply both extensions in the same plot (repeat axis labels **and** split over multiple plots)

Example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = mpg) +
  geom_point(aes(x = cty, y = hwy))

## Default
p + facet_wrap(~ manufacturer)
## Repeat x-axis labels
p + lemon::facet_rep_wrap(~ manufacturer, repeat.tick.labels = "x")
## Split over multiple plots
p + ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate(~ manufacturer, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, page = 1)
```

How can I combine `facet_rep_wrap` and `facet_wrap_paginate`?

Internally, they call `ggproto(NULL, FacetWrapRepeatLabels, ...)` and `ggproto(NULL, FacetWrapPaginate, ...)`, respectively. Can I combine the two objects `FacetWrapRepeatLabels` and `FacetWrapPaginate`? How can I do this?